# Can we use WSO2 governance registry with other ESB or integration Products?

Tags: wso2, integration, cluster-computing, esb, wso2-governance-registry

Is it possible to use WSO2 greg with other ESB Products or it can only be used with WSO2 Products?

Thanks
Jagjeet

Comment: You can integrate WSO2 GReg with other products, eg case-study: http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/05/mule-wso2-registry-integration-jos-dirksen

Answer (score 0):

GReg 4.6.0 supports Oracle Service Bus too. Please refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Oracle+Service+Bus

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way to do that with Mule Studio may be using some eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Please find below links,

- [Wso2 GReg with other wso2 products](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/WSO2)
- [Mule and WSO2 Registry integration](http://www.smartjava.org/content/mule-and-wso2-registry-integration)
- [Wso2 GReg with Oracle Service Bus](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Oracle+Service+Bus)
- [Wso2 GReg with Alfresco](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Alfresco)